# Two title bars for all windows

Tags: unity

I have found that I have two title bars for all window screens.
The attached images describe the problem, I can minimize or close the window from any title bar.

Note: the attached screenshots for maximized Windows.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc4ka.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaViU.png]

Comment: That's normal, what's the problem?

Comment: Actually, i didn't use to see that, i don't think it's the default behavior.

Comment: It's called global menu and it's the default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm, Well don't worry my friend this is not as unusual as it may seem. You see one of those lil' buggers will stay at the top of the screen at all times with your context menu items residing upon it. Whilst the other will stay with the particular dimensions of your application unique window frame... In other word one is a toolbar at the top of the screen... You get the picture...

Comment: So, there is no solution to return it back as usual, just one titlebar if the window maximized !!

Comment: you got it. and please if this answered your question mark itas answered. Thanx -Bill